# Unable to Untar or Unzip from SFTP connection

Tags: bash, tar, sftp, zip

I am able to zip and transfer files using SFTP with the below commands from my script:

```
zipfilename="Order_$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").zip"
echo "Start Execution" $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") >> "$logfile"
echo "Zipping Files" >> "$logfile"
zip $zipfilename order*.xml
echo "Zipping Success" >> "$logfile"
echo "put $zipfilename In" | sshpass -p $PSWRD sftp user@xxx.xxx.com >> "$logfile"
```

Below is the result:

```
sftp> put Order_20190830221440.zip In
Uploading Order_20190830221440.zip to /In/Order_20190830221440.zip
```

I am able to confirm that the zipped file is getting transferred successfully.
However, when I try to unzip it via SFTP I get an error. I am using the below commands:

```
echo "unzip $zipfilename" | sshpass -p $PSWRD sftp user@xxx.xxx.com >> "$logfile"
```

The error is as follows:

```
sftp> unzip Order_20190830221440.zip
Invalid command.
```

I've tried this both for `zip` and `tar` approaches.
Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unzip a file on a remote server with SFTP. That's just not possible.

---

If you have a shell access to the server, you can unzip the file using shell:

```
sshpass -p $PSWRD ssh User@xxx.xxx.com unzip $zipfilename
```

---

As you do not seem to have a shell access, then unless you have yet another access (like some web-based control panel), you won't be able to unzip the file on the server.

Comment: i tried that but it came back with `Request failed: Non SCP Command: unzip`

Comment: i think this is the right track, it just needs to have `sshpass -p $PSWRD ssh User@xxx.xxx.com 'unzip $zipfilename'`

Comment: So does it work with the quotes? You should not need them. They will actually prevent resolution of the `zipfilename`. It rather looks like you do not have a shell access. Or do you?

Comment: sorry yes you're correct, it didn't work. How do I determine if I have shell access?

Comment: Can you login with `ssh User@xxx.xxx.com`?

Comment: i tried that but got the error `ssh User@xxx.xxx.com
User@xxx.xxx.com's password:
Connection to xxx.xxx.com closed.` seems I don't have Shell access. is this correct?

Comment: Yes it looks like you do not. Unless you have yet another access (like some web based control panel), you won't be able to unzip the file on the server.